# Method calling issues

Tags: python

```
#!/usr.byn/python3

import struct

class Fat:
def __init__(self, fat):
self._fat

    def entryValue(self, cluster):
    value = struct.unpackf=t('I', fat[cluster*4:cluster*4+4])[0]
    return value

    def isAllocated(self, cluster):
    return self.entryValue(cluster)!=0

    def nextCluster(self, cluster):
      if (self.entryValue(cluster)==0 or
      self.entryValue(cluster)==0x0fffffff):
        return None
          else:
        return self.entryValue(cluster)

     def clusterChain(self,cluster):
    list1 =[]
    while isAllocated:
    for item in isAllocated:
    continue
    list1.append
    value = 0




''' make empty list, if cluster is allocated append it to list
if not allocated start at new cluster, return list
make do while loop'''

def main():
with open('/home/louis/Downloads/fat-only.dd', 'rb') as f:
fat=f.read()
fat1=Fat(fat)
```

As i'm still learning python, I still have some code writing issues and any help would be greatly appreciated. As mentioned in the comment in my third method there I need to check to see if the cluster is allocated or not, and if it is it gets added to the list, and if not it just goes on to the next cluster. Just very confused on how to continue or what to change in the third method, I know that at least my first two are good from some previous help I sought out.

Comment: You should change the title to not get downvoted here, also your code isn't indented.

Comment: remember that in python block of code are defined by its identation level, unlike other lengujes where other marker are use like `{` and `}` to define said block

Comment: well that's the issue when I copied and pasted this from an e-mail, was working on it on a different laptop so e-mailed it to myself and copied it on here, the indentation level got all messed up. Thought I did indent though when posted, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Just some observations:

```
class Fat:
    def __init__(self, fat):
    self._fat # <------------------- this should be given a value

def clusterChain(self,cluster):
    list1 =[]
    while isAllocated: # <---------- this doesn't actually call the function
        for item in isAllocated:
            continue
        list1.append # <------------ this does nothing
    value = 0 # <------------------- this looks undefined
```

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback as for the observations you pointed out i'll try saying what I was trying to do. For the first one I have no clue what value to add. For the second in the third method I am trying to write a for while loop. With the third one in the list1.append when it finds a cluster that is allocated it's supposed to be added to the list, and the fourth one is still undefined. I am just drawing a huge blank on how to fix the third method correctly.